# Ubuntu Gnome Keyboard error

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I wanted Gnome GUI instead of Unity and I installed it and it worked fine, but some time later it started having the following error:

When switching keyboards via mouse, the keyboard itself changes but the language bar is still the main language (English). When switching keyboards via hotkey, the keyboard switches to the secondary language, but then after pushing that hotkey again it doesn't switch back to the main language.

It's important, sometimes this switching works, but suddenly it does as I described.

P.S. this is my first question and please edit if you think that here is some errors and don't be strict :)